# Which countries does this patent cover? Is it possible to design around it?

Tags: law, international

In reference to the patent: [US20130223070](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130223070)

Answer (score 0):

The application was filed in the European, U.S.A., and Canadian patent offices. The U.S. application has been granted and issued as [US 8529082 B](https://www.google.com/patents/US8529082) and [US 9103539 B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US9103539). The [EU application](https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP13710198) and the [CA application](http://brevets-patents.ic.gc.ca/opic-cipo/cpd/eng/patent/2901771/summary.html) are still under examination. Therefore, currently the invention is protected in U.S.A only.

To design around it, you need to refer to the claims in the issued patents, not the patent application.